# How to disallow parallel INSERTs in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2

I have an `ON INSERT` trigger in PostgreSQL 9.2, which does some calculation and injects extra data into every row being inserted. The problem is that I don't want any two `INSERT` transactions to happen in parallel. I want them to go one by one, because my calculations have to be incremental and take into account previous calculation results. Is it possible to achieve this somehow?

I'm trying to create a rolling balance on a list of payments:

```
id | amount | balance
----------------------
 1 |     50 |      50
 2 |    130 |     180
 3 |    -75 |     105
 4 |     15 |     120
```

The `balance` has to be calculated on every `INSERT` as a previous balance plus a new payment `amount`. If `INSERT`s happen in parallel I have duplicates in `balance` column, which is logical. I need to find a way how to enforce them to be executed in a strict sequential order.

Comment: You can calculate that balance "on the fly". Why do you think you need a trigger?

Comment: It's a multi-million record table, "on-fly" takes many seconds, since my real-life example is more complicated and this `balance` column is calculated in a more complex way

Comment: I can think of two possible ways: make your transactions serializable or lock the table prior to the insert (you do know about the ability of the window functions to calculate a running sum?)

Comment: Yeah, [`SERIALIZABLE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/transaction-iso.html#XACT-SERIALIZABLE) sound like the way to go here.

Answer (score 1):

`SERIALIZABLE` transaction didn't help, mostly because of the problem explained [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/transaction-iso.html#XACT-SERIALIZABLE). I simply get errors on most of transactions: `could not serialize access due to read/write dependencies among transactions`.

What did help was an explicit `LOCK` before every `INSERT`:

```
LOCK TABLE receipt IN SHARE ROW EXCLUSIVE MODE;
INSERT INTO receipt ...
```

All inserts are happening consequently now.

Comment: `LOCK`s are clear / certain ways to solve this, but performance-wise very heavy. `SERIALIZE` is ideally supposed to be tried in a retry-loop and then your observation is quite normal, just that which poison you end up taking, clearly depends on which drawback is acceptable.